# how to add up values with same textfield name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have two select menus, that contain values, my intention is to multiple the values of the two select menus and show them in a `TextField`,

I've done this successfully carried this out by doing this :

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function updatesum() {

document.form1.textfield3.value = (document.form1.selectt.value -0) * (document.form1.selecttt.value -0); 
}

//--></script>

 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="val.php">
 <label><strong><br />
         Chelsea vs Arsenal</strong>
         <select name="selectt" onchange="updatesum()">
           <option value="0">select</option>
           <option value="100">100</option>
           <option value="200">200</option>
         </select>
       </label>
       <label><strong>odds</strong>
         <select name="selecttt" onchange="updatesum()">
           <option value="0">select</option>
           <option value="100">L</option>
           <option value="200">W</option>
             <option value="400">D</option>
         </select>
       </label>

       <input name="textfield3" type="text" /><br />

       </form>
```

Now I'm trying to do a double of this select menus using the same name attribute, but it refuses to calculate.

This is what I'vve tried :

```
document.form1.textfield3.value = (document.form1.selectt.value -0) * (document.form1.selecttt.value -0)    }

//--></script>

 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="val.php">

       <label><strong><br />
         Chelsea vs Arsenal</strong>
         <select name="selectt" onchange="updatesum()">
           <option value="0">select</option>
           <option value="100">100</option>
           <option value="200">200</option>
         </select>
       </label>
       <label><strong>odds</strong>
         <select name="selecttt" onchange="updatesum()">
           <option value="0">select</option>
           <option value="100">L</option>
           <option value="200">W</option>
             <option value="400">D</option>
         </select>
       </label>

       <input name="textfield3" type="text" /><br /> <label><strong><br />
         Chelsea vs Arsenal</strong>
         <select name="selectt" onchange="updatesum()">
           <option value="0">select</option>
           <option value="100">100</option>
           <option value="200">200</option>
         </select>
       </label>
       <label><strong>odds</strong>
         <select name="selecttt" onchange="updatesum()">
           <option value="0">select</option>
           <option value="100">L</option>
           <option value="200">W</option>
             <option value="400">D</option>
         </select>
       </label>

       <input name="textfield3" type="text" /><br />

       </form>
```

I was hoping it would work this way, but it didn't, how can I achieve this?

Comment: not clear with your question

Comment: from my explaination, i have two select menus that i multiply together to show a result in a textfield, i now want to have another double select menu, but with same name attr

Comment: name atrr selectt and selecttt

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you are trying to say but i have write some pseudocode hope this will help you...

pseudocode

```
<script>
var globalVariable=1;
function updateSum(){
//get current element value
globalVariable*=document.form.select.value
textfield.value = globalVariable;
}
</script>
```

Comment: what i ws try to explain ws, that i have a snippet that multiplies the value of two select menus and shows the result in a textfield, now i want to make a repeat of the same select menus on the same form using the same name attr and still be able to do my calculations, do u understand nw